# Java: javax.mail как подставить имя в поле from

Tags: email, smtp, java

В общем ситуация такая, отправляю письма через javax.mail, приведу кусок кода:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromMail));
msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toMail));
msg.setSubject(Subject);

MimeBodyPart msgPart = new MimeBodyPart();
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(msgPart);

msgPart.setText(bodyMail, "UTF-8");
msgPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"");

msg.setContent(multipart);

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(smtp_host, smtp_port, smtp_user, smtp_pass);
msg.saveChanges();
transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

Вопрос в том, как мне в поле FROM подставить имя отправителя, т.е. чтобы было

FROM: Вася Пупкин [pupkin@mail.com](mailto:pupkin@mail.com)

Не могу сообразить, у setFrom() может быть аргумент только InternetAddress :( Может быть как-то через setHeader()?

Answer (score 2):

В общем решил я этот вопрос, нужно было сделать:

```
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromMail, fromName));
```

Покопался в конструкторах InternetAddress() и нашел :) Может кому будет полезно.

Comment: Такой вопрос уже был здесь на хэшкоде.. пол года назад где-то


Вот он: http://hashcode.ru/questions/7802/

Comment: Вообще там вопрос про кодировку был задан. Однако, два дня поисков в гугле и решение было найдено на stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: А в javadoc в описании конструктора InternetAddress() этого не было ?

Comment: @Shamanis да, но ведь вопрос и ответ содержали ответ на ваш вопрос и даже в более сложном случае.

@avp документацию у нивичков читать не принято (и ещё у некоторых категорий разработчиков).

Comment: @cy6erGn0m не надо грубить вот только. Весь код целиком и полностью написан по-документации и прочитал я ее не мало, но с этим случаем слегка растерялся, потому что смотреть начал метод setFrom(), только потом до меня дошло, что тут ключевую роль играет конструктор InternetAddress(). Опыта согласен у меня не много, но такие ресурсы и созданы для того, чтобы этим опытом делится :)

Comment: @Shamanis, молодец, что разобрался. Мне (если честно) было просто лень залезть в доку.